# Etymology of "hen" as a term of endearment in Scottish

Tags: etymology, scottish-english

I just stumbled across [this older video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Sutrxcwj7U) of a girl trying to "talk" to Alexa (the voice assistant). She says "I am trying to talk to you, hen". Now, I am not a native English speaker, but I am familiar with the endearing term "honey", also sometimes written "hunny" or even "hun" or "hon" depending on the pronunciation. However, the pronunciation "hen" made me think of the word for a female chicken.

I've heard the word "chicks" to refer to females (but I think this is generally not an appreciated term? - again, not a native speaker), so there is a connection to use terms for poultry to refer to people. So my question is, in Scottish, what is the root/etymology of "hen"? Is it related to "honey" or to "hen" (chicken), or maybe something completely unrelated?

Comment: There's also _hinny_, used in North-East England. Dictionaries say they are variants of _honey_.

Comment: I always thought ***hinny*** was to do with horses *(The offspring of a she-ass by a stallion)*. But I now discover that's a different word with a different origin, unconnected to the term of endearment derived from ***honey***.

Comment: Different parts of the north of England also use generic 'friendly' terms; off the top of my head, West Yorkshire has 'love', non-bird-related,  Nottingham has 'duck', the origin of which I have not the foggiest, but maybe coincidentally is a female drake. Hen itself stretches south of the border at least as far as Newcastle. Liverpool has 'chuck' [another word for hen, as in the infantile term chucky-egg]. All of these are used to anyone but not male to male, only the other 3 alternatives [MF, FM, FF].

Comment: I always thought hinny was from hen, though I've never met a Geordie who would have given it a second thought. They use the two interchangeably.

Comment: @Tetsujin - _Duck_ is used in Derbyshire too. Its use as an endearment goes back at least to Shakespeare's time - in the play scene in _A Midsummer Night's Dream_, Bottom  (as Pyramus) addresses the dead Thisbe "Oh, dainty duck".

Comment: IME Geordies use ‘**pet**’.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the DSL, the term *hen* is often used in place of the British *chicken*; e.g. *hen-broth* and *hen-hertit* (hen-hearted). Other diminutives include *henny* and *hennie*.

> “Mr Erskine,” said the lady [Miss Henrietta], as the wine was beginning to circulate, ”they say that ye’re a great man for making puns: could ye make a pun, d’ye think, on me.” “Od, Hennie,” the wit instantly replied; [“you might be making puns yourself now: I'm sure, *Hennie* though ye be, ye‘re *nae* chicken](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Scottish_jests_and_anecdotes_To_which_ar/kq5bAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E2%80%9Cthey%20say%20that%20ye%27re%20a%20great%20man%20for%20making%20puns:%20could%20ye%20mak%20a%20pun,%20d%27ye%20think,%20on%20me.%E2%80%9D&pg=PA65&printsec=frontcover).”
> *Scottish Jests and Anecdotes* 1832.

It continues to be used in print today as testified by this [example](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/hen_n1):

Sc. 2000 *The Herald* 21 Jun 35:
“I resisted the temptation to be patronising and said: "I'm not sure how one does it, hen, but this is how I do it.”

From *Dictionaries of the Scots Language* (DSL)

> **Hen** *n.*
> “Used as a term of endearment or familiarity for a girl or woman”.

From the website  [Scots Language Centre](https://www.scotslanguage.com/articles/view/id/6154).

> This use first appears in the DSL cited from Alexander Ross’s *Helenore* or the *Fortunate Shepherdess* of 1768:
>
> > “Then says to Nory, rest you bony hen”.
>
> Staying with bonnie hens, Burns, in his poem *In Simmer* (1792), writes:
>
> > “Tak this frae me, ma bonie hen: It’s plenty beets the luver’s fire!”.
>
> The word also appears in Irvine Welsh’s *Trainspotting* (1993):
>
> > “Nivir mind, Alice. Nivir mind, hen. Here's Nina wi the tea...”.

Author: Pauline Cairns Speitel

Comment: Where does it come from in terms of its linguistic origin? Honey, poultry, or something else? I guess "bony hen" would favor "poultry".

Comment: @BramVanroy I have included other sources to support the claim that *hen* is the Scots word for chicken, and not a diminutive of *honey*

Comment: Unlike 8 other people I seem to missing the part of this answer which addresses the "Etymology of "hen" as a term of endearment in Scottish".

Comment: @JudyN.  The DSL citations?? The term *hen* is used as a term of affection, similar to *duck(y)*, *chick*, *bunny*, *sweet pea* and *sweetie-pie*. The term *hen* refers to the bird, it is not a shortening of *honey* as the OP surmised.  For etymologists it is impossible to place a specific date on when this usage first appeared in speech, they have to limit themselves to finding the first instance in *print* when "hen" obviously did not refer to a living or dead female chicken.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I still am not seeing any of this in your answer??
To clarify: your references which link to a chicken make no link to a term of endearment, and vice-versa

Comment: I don't know what to say then. If you want the etymology of hen that would not be really be on point, but here you are: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hen#:~:text=From%20Middle%20English%20hen%2C%20from,(%E2%80%9Cto%20sing%E2%80%9D).

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are asserting that the term of endearment *is* the word that is used for chicken (– this is the question that we are aiming to resolve). But you have provided nothing that substantiates this connection!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Where is your assertion "The term hen is used as a term of affection, similar to duck(y), chick, bunny, sweet pea and sweetie-pie. The term hen refers to the bird, it is not a shortening of honey as the OP surmised" substantiated in your references?

Comment: @JudyN. I have written that it refers to chicken because that is what it says in the DSL, please click on the link(which is in the answer): https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/hen_n1. I have to go now, it's getting late. I'll respond later.

Comment: @BramVanroy 'bony/bonny/bonie/bonnie' all mean "pretty" in these examples. They have nothing to do with bones.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh, good point. Thanks!

Comment: @JudyN. `your references which link to a chicken make no link to a term of endearment, and vice-versa` But the first link does tell me that *H(h)ennie* was the name for a chicken because the pun wouldn't work otherwise [paraphrased] "You might be Hennie, but you're not a chicken” There's no doubt that the term specifically refers to the fowl not to *honey*.  May I ask why greybeard's answer is more satisfactory than mine? There's no downvote on his answer.

Answer (score 7):

Hen taken from the common cock and hen - alluding to male and female.

OED:

**Hen**

> **II.3.a. A woman; a wife.** *Now colloquial*. See also old hen n.
>
> In early use chiefly in figurative contexts, often explicitly
> contrasted with cock.
>
> ?1555 For beinge hym selfe a cocke of the game, he thought her [sc. a
> certeyne fayre Mistres] to be a henne of the same sorte, and trusted
> well to haue some iolly good treadynge by the way. *Image of Idlenesse
> xiii. sig. C.viv*
>
> 2017 The wee hen from Dumfries performed a zombie dance routine to
> Michael Jackson's Thriller. *Daily Mail 13 December*

And in the 18th century the "endearment" aspect takes hold:

> II.3.b. *Scottish colloquial.* **As a form of address for a girl or
> woman, typically as a term of affection or endearment.**
>
> 1768 Then says to Nory, rest you bony hen.
> *A. Ross, Fortunate Shepherdess i.*
>
> 2011 Don't worry, hen. It's going to be fine. *A. McCall Smith, Bertie
> plays Blues (2013) xxxiii. 127*